# Extend two backbone collections into another backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have

```
CollectionA = Backbone.collection.extend({ a : function() {} });
CollectionB = Backbone.collection.extend({ b : function() {} });
```

How can I define `CollectionC` as a collection with all the functions from `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` and also its own function `c`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix the prototypes of `CollectionA` and `CollectionB` into the the prototype of `CollectionC` with the help of [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) :

```
var A = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    a: function() { console.log('a'); },
    croak: function() { console.log('croak a'); }
});
var B = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    b: function() { console.log('b'); },
    croak: function() { console.log('croak b'); }
});
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    c: function() { console.log('c'); },
    croak: function() { console.log('croak c'); }
});

_.extend(C.prototype, A.prototype, B.prototype);

var c = new C();
c.a(); // outputs a
c.b(); // outputs b
c.c(); // outputs c
```

Note that if a method is defined multiple times, it will be shadowed by the last one mixed in: `c.croak();` will output *b*

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/yjb3g3e3/

If you want to prevent the shadowing of some methods, you can either pick/omit them from the mixin:

```
_.extend(C.prototype, 
    _.omit(A.prototype, 'croak'),
    _.omit(B.prototype, 'croak')
);

c.croak(); // outputs c
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/yjb3g3e3/1/

or set that method on C afterwards:

```
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    c: function() { console.log('c'); }
});

_.extend(C.prototype, A.prototype, B.prototype);
C.prototype.croak = function() { console.log('croak c'); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/yjb3g3e3/3/

Comment: what if i would like to stop overriding functions of Collection C. means C also has a function named 'b'. and i would like function b in Collection C does not get overridden.

Comment: Don't mix those methods in:) I added some examples for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
_.extend(CollectionC,CollectionB,CollectionA)
```